# NaN Javascript & Jquery error when trying to concatinate a number and a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, nan

I am trying to implement the following code but the value returned to the id on page is populated with the NaN (Not a Number) error. Has anyone got any suggestions what I can do here? I have been battling this for over an hour now, so your assistance would be appreciated.

```
setInterval( function(){ 
    var b = $('input#ien_val').val();
    var ien;
    for (ien = 0; ien < b; ien++) {
        var encuser = parseInt($('#enutt'+ien).html()); 
        var enteam = parseInt($('#enttotalday'+ien).html()); 
        var enoffset = (encuser/enteam)*100;
        $('#tten' + ien).html(enoffset + '%');
    }
},2000);
```

As per comments below I have added an example of my issue here http://jsbin.com/tobilonepu/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youre trying to loop through `$('#enttotalday'+ien)` but there is only one value there so its casuing the issue. working code:

```
setInterval( function(){ 
    var b = $('input#ien_val').val();
    var ien;
    for (ien = 1; ien < b; ien++) {
        // add parseInt
        var encuser = parseInt($('#enutt'+ien).val());
        // add parseInt
        var enteam = parseInt($('#enttotalday').val()); 

        var enoffset = (encuser/enteam)*100;
        $('#tten' + ien).html(enoffset + '%');
    }
},2000);
```

jsbin here - http://jsbin.com/nivoxuwufa/1/

Comment: No worries. Sometimes you can get to close to things and just miss little things. Glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Since you are performing arithmatic operations, you need to make sure that the values that you have are either `Number`/`integer`/`float` and not `string`. `.val()` generally gets you a `string`.

Replace:

```
var encuser = $('#enutt'+ien).val(); 
var enteam = $('#enttotalday'+ien).val();
```

with:

```
var encuser = Number($('#enutt'+ien).val()); 
var enteam = Number($('#enttotalday'+ien).val());
```

Instead of `Number()`, you can use `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()` as per your requirement.

Readup:

- [`Number()` | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)
- [`parseInt()` | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)
- [`parseFloat()` | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)

Comment: I'd tried Number() and parseInt(), I hadn't tried parseFloat so just gave that one a go - I'm still getting an NaN error... It passes the % symbol back to the <td>'s with the id value its at but not the numeric value... Thoughts?

Comment: @Kai Try it with `parseFloat`. Do you have any special characters in the values? These functions expect a valid number.

Comment: There are no special characters except at the end when I am trying to return a string that will contain a % symbol... See this here... http://jsbin.com/tobilonepu/1/

Comment: @Kai You mentioned the wrong ID for total in your jQuery code. Replace `$('#enttotalday'+ien)` with `$('#enttotalday')`. See this updated jsBin: http://jsbin.com/xasidewari/1/

Answer (score 0):

You have to transform encuser and enteam to numbers first. Try something like this

```
setInterval( function(){ 
    var b = $('input#ien_val').val();
    var ien;
    for (ien = 0; ien < b; ien++) {
        var encuser = parseFloat($('#enutt'+ien).val()); 
        var enteam = parseFloat($('#enttotalday'+ien).val()); 
        var enoffset = (encuser/enteam)*100;
        $('#tten' + ien).html(enoffset + '%');
    }
},2000);
```

Readmore about parseInt, parseFloat & Number:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number
- https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt
- https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat

### Update

Working: http://jsbin.com/mezamakopi/2/edit

Comment: I've tried Number() and parseInt(), I hadn't tried parseFloat so just gave that one a go - I'm still getting an NaN error... It passes the % symbol back to the <td>'s with the id value its at but not the numeric value... Thoughts?

Comment: @Kai Got it! You had wrong markup and the "ien"-iterator should start at 1 http://jsbin.com/mezamakopi/2/edit

Answer (score 0):

You should parse dom value to number use `parseInt` or `parseFloat`. Based on that the code should look like this.

```
setInterval( function(){ 
    var b = $('input#ien_val').val();
    var ien;
    for (ien = 0; ien < b; ien++) {
        // add parseInt
        var encuser = parseInt($('#enutt'+ien).val());
        // add parseInt
        var enteam = parseInt($('#enttotalday'+ien).val()); 

        var enoffset = (encuser/enteam)*100;
        $('#tten' + ien).html(enoffset + '%');
    }
},2000);
```

Hope it could help you. Cheers.

Comment: I've tried Number() and parseInt() for theose var's in previous attemps to debug this prior to posting here, I hadn't tried parseFloat so just gave that one a go - I'm still getting an NaN error... It passes the % symbol back to the <td>'s with the id value its at but not the numeric value... Thoughts?

Comment: Could you update you question with the real example of the code so I could help you to debug it?